# Css gradient: How to draw a line which is thick in middle but thin at the ends?

Tags: css

[image]

I am trying with the gradient code which looks like the following below:

```
-webkit-gradient(left, #fff, #000, #fff);
```

I know I can assign percentages to the colors but I am not sure how to add the variant thickness.

Comment: Just ping me if my answer doesn't solve your doubt, I closed it because I see no difference between this question and the other question I linked with.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it is indeed the same thing I am looking for but selected answer has too much of css for this single line :D I think I am better with using image instead of using that much css

Comment: Sorry, I take my words back, I just noticed that it was just vendor specific css which was adding too much too the code

Comment: It's my answer only :) and the amount of CSS written is to support cross browser, but now I don't think you will need all that CSS just to get that effect, I'll update my answer there.